# Find $m \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\varphi(m)$ is a prime number.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, totient-function

> Find all natural numbers $m$ such that $\varphi(m)$ is a prime number.

Let $a$ is coprime with $m$. By using Euler's theorem and Fermat's little theorem, we have $a^{\varphi(m)} \equiv 1 \mod m$ and $a^{m-1} \equiv 1 \mod m$.

This is the only thing I have. Please help me. Thank you very much.

Comment: If you just need an example, $m=3$ works.

Comment: I think I have to find all $m$ which satisfies this condition.

Comment: Show that $\varphi(m)$ is always even (except when it’s equal to $1$). What does this imply about its possible prime values? (David is not correct, btw. Your use of FLT is also not correct, you weren’t told anything about $m$ being prime.)

Comment: A strategy you always have available for this kind of question is to just start computing values of $\varphi(m)$ and see what kind of patterns you notice. Give it a try!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $m$ is prime, then $\phi(m)=m-1$ is prime only if $m=3$. ($m=2$ doesn't work, so $m$ is odd, then $m-1$ is even, and $2$ is the only even prime).

If $m$ isn't prime, there are two cases:

1. $m=p^k$ with $p$ prime.
2. $m=pq$ with $(p,q)=1$, $\,p,q\not =1$.

If $m=p^k$, then $\phi(m)=p^{k-1}(p-1)$ is prime, then $p=2$, $k=2$, so $m=4$.

If $m=pq$, then since $\varphi(m)=\varphi(p)\varphi(q)$ is prime, meaning one of them, say $\varphi(p)=1$, then $p=2$. Since $\varphi(q)$ is prime, since $q$ can't contains factors of $2$, using the same reasoning above, then it can only be $3$.

This gives the only $m$ to be $3,4,6$.

Comment: Not $m=4$?  Something must have changed since I did my 1800 ft stair climb this morning ... .

Comment: @OscarLanzi opps, will fix soon

Comment: Why $m-1$ is a prime if and only if $m=3$. For $m>3$, if $m=3k+2$ then $m-1=3k+1$, I wonder how to prove $3k+1$ is not a prime.

Comment: @FactorY It's because if $m>2$ is prime, then $m-1$ is even.

Comment: We do not have $\phi(pq)=\phi(p)\phi(q)$ when $p$ and $q$ are not relatively prime like $p=q=2$.  That's how $m=4$ is missed.  Can you correct?

Comment: @OscarLanzi Thanks for pointing it out, fixed.

Comment: Thank you very much @David Cheng.